How to deal with overtaking personal space and decision making?
Some time ago I had to deal with overtaking personal space and personal decision making by some close relatives. He/They were some family members (Not in the same house or family). They advised my family members regarding my studies, job, etc. And some of my family members took this advice and put pressure on me.
I was really annoyed by that. I felt like they were trying to control me and make me a puppet. So, I was really annoyed and angry.
According to Buddhism, how I/someone should manage these situations?

do u think they are going to protect u forever?  hmm...yes i guess that makes sense

No. That's why I ask, what should the response be? It's not about protection. About putting pressure on others through family relationships with their opinions.

Vassakārasutta might interest you.  It says the following and other good advice..

“As long as the Vajjis meet frequently and have many meetings, they
can expect growth, not decline.

To me it means keep the dialogue open. Then you have a voice, and not imploding.

idk where u r from, but the cultural aspect might be difficult to overcome. still the modern world expects less..

Here are a few suggestions:

Reframe the situation and try to see it as an invitation to growth and a chance to deepen your patience, compassion and self-awareness - rather than as a disturbing nuisance.
Develop healthy boundaries to avoid exploitation. Maintain your personal space. Allow yourself and others to 'breathe' without feeling trapped by too much interaction.
Practice mindfulness meditation, becoming aware of your thoughts and emotions without judgement. When you feel these emotions rising, can you take a breath and observe them as they are - transient visitors in the mind? This can help you to observe the situation with clarity rather than being swept away by intense feelings. Where are these feelings of annoyance and anger coming from? What are your own expectations? Is there attachment, e.g. to autonomy, that ignites this fire within you?
Practice loving-kindness (metta) with those who may be unknowingly causing suffering through their actions. Communicate your needs calmly and compassionately, but assertively if necessary. When we act from a place of kindness rather than reaction, even challenging dynamics can often be transformed.


Their actions are one thing, maybe a problem.
Your anger is another thing -- it's easy to feel, "I'm right to be angry because of their actions" -- but if you're angry, now you have two problems!
For example it probably wouldn't be wise for me to be angry with the people I work with. I guess the first thing to try is to "see the situation as it really is" -- which IMO includes "without anger", given that anger distorts.
Some people are more stressed by their families than at work -- perhaps because it's harder to change your family than to change your work. They might feel justified in being angry at family -- "there's no other choice!" -- in a way that they wouldn't with other adults. Instead perhaps you should be even more careful with family than at work, to remain "good-natured" etc.
Buddhism might also say that family has a duty to advise you. Something I heard once from a Pacifist was, "I'll discuss anything with anyone -- but if it becomes an argument, then I'll say, 'You're right!', and walk away." My parents didn't pressure me much -- offered their advice and opinion. In retrospect perhaps I should have been more willing to discuss it.
I'm not sure how to understand your saying "puppet". I guess we play various "roles" -- student, husband, coworker, friend, etc. -- and play them "willingly", I hope: choose what you want to do, where to invest your effort. I think it's not entirely about what you call "control" -- it's about "cooperation". Also an intelligent partner is IMO greater than a mindless one (a puppet).

Buddha once convinced of the suffering of people took the lonely decision to eradicate suffering. It was a tough decision involving leaving palace , wife , wealth and all the luxuries.
Similarly if you think that what you wish to do has strong relevance to society’s welfare then you must do it at any cost. Disregard the pressure and do what you believe in.

When people give me advice, I would usually try to discern what is their intentions and how close is my relationship with them. It is hard to figure out people’s intentions especially with those whom we are not close to. But with people whom we have interacted over the years and who had shown love, care and concern for our well-being, it is a different matter. With such people (close relatives or friends), we know they genuinely care for our welfare. If they do give advice, I would tend to pay closer attention and be more willing to discuss things over with them.
However, I find this is not the case if they hardly show any concern about our or others’ welfare. If they did not or have not ever gone out of their way to help us or others either in the past or at present. Or if they did not take an interest in our likes, dislikes, habits or whatever it is we are doing in our life. There are some distant relatives whom we only meet once or twice a year! To them, we are just in-laws, cousins and so on; related by kinship but not the kinhood that comes from receiving and reciprocating care and concern. Sadly, this situation can happen even amongst immediate family members. I learned that blood is not always thicker than water.
Unlike the Buddha, we have to suss out the intentions of another by watching their habits over a period of time. If we realize that they are prideful, selfish and greedy then normally any advice from such people would only be fit for the trash bins. Unfortunately, it is not easy to find people around us who are sincere, honest, kind and caring in their disposition. Even amongst immediate family members, love can be selfish. Intentions are not always pure whether in ourselves or in others.
What is true love? When I was younger, I thought it is what a person says or expresses to another. Now, I realized that it is what a person does for another i.e. it is not something verbal but it is something acted out over a long period of time that reveal the presence and extent of one’s love for another.
Expecting true love from another is hard. Perhaps, we can only really depend on ourselves to truly love ourselves. However, in this I realize there is no guarantee as well. I had failed myself many times in the past. Similarly, I seen the same happening to many people that I knew closely over the years. Again, I don’t think it is because we lack self-love, rather it is something that we do not understand and as a result is doing wrongly. It is the understanding that true love is about commitment and responsibility whether it is to ourselves or to others and seeing it through.
The Buddha once give an advice to Ven. Rāhula in MN61.

In the same way, Rāhula, bodily actions, verbal actions, & mental actions are to be done with repeated reflection.....would it lead to self-affliction, to the affliction of others, or to both?

I think very few are willing to commit to such self-reflections even though we are responsible for our own well-being (and those of others). If someone whom we disdain and spar with, repeatedly over the years, were to give us some advice that grates on the ears. Do we choose to uphold our pride/ego or instead our future happiness/well-being? Do we discard the advice without listening or be responsible and committed to ourselves and our future well-being by at least hearing it out (without prejudices); then carefully evaluate the advice for its truthfulness and relevancy? Lastly, to follow the advice through even if it was from our enemies? Perhaps, true love is difficult thing.

The Buddha said quite simply:

MN43:13.2: “There are two conditions for the arising of right view:
MN43:13.3: the voice of another and rational application of mind.

Apply your mind rationally to what is heard and not to personal space.
UPDATE 30m LATER: On second thought, since "personal space" is a currently accepted concept, I would add the following to my rather terse comment above:
Also apply your mind rationally to the form that we all talk about as "personal space".  The reason to do that is that the Buddha also said:

MN13:30.1: And what is the escape from forms?
MN13:30.2: Removing and giving up desire and greed for forms: this is the escape from forms.

